# Getting Bool(False) on custom module when calling my model

Tags: magento-1.9, resource-model

I am not able to call my model each time it gives bool(False).
table is creating in database from below code. to check my model i stored some data manually in table.
[image: Model code of config.xml file]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I already tried 
Mage::getModel('weebsly_dbscript/formdata');
and 
Mage::getModel('dbscript/formdata');
setup.php file is also there

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that you should write `$this->_init('weebsly_dbscript/formdata'` wherever it is possible (instead of `$this->_init('dbscript/formdata'`) because the alias of your model is `weebsly_dbscript`.

Comment: I have made changes as you suggest but still facing same issue.